# Codesign application with provisioning profile on different account

Tags: iphone, provisioning, game-center, app-id

I'm working on a game which uses Game Center for multiplayer gaming.

Now the time has come to test the game with another person.

At first - I thought it would have been easy - just send him the provisioning file which has been created with my developer account (and not his) along with the project.

Turns out he can't compile the application with my provisioning file, which is the only way from getting the dreaded "This game is not recognized by Game Center" message.

I can sign in, and even Search for Players - but whenever he signs the application with his own provisioning profile (which is a wildcard in terms of App identifiers) he can't sign into Game Center because the game isn't recognized. He has a 'Test User' account linked to my iTunes Connect account - but it seems that he needs to sign the application with my provisioning profile - which will only sign with my certificate.

How do I get around this?

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you are using different Developer Accounts with different App ID's. The Game Center Game is tied to a specific Bundle Identifier which consists of the Bundle Seed ID and your Wildcard App ID. His provisioning profile for his Bundle would have a different Bundle Seed ID and possibly a different App ID which results in Game Center not recognising the game for your Tester.

For him to have access to the same App ID, you'd need to have a Team Developer Account to use multiple certificates for the same Provisioning Profile and App ID.

Instead, You could distribute an IPA to your Test User for him/her to test. I've described the steps briefly below from the top of my head:

1. Add his Device UUID to your provisioning profile and import it into Xcode
2. Create your Entitlements file (check out the guide linked below) and Set your Scheme to iOS Device and Click on Product -> Archive
3. Once Archived, In Organiser find your Archived App, click on it and choose the Share Button
4. The Contents should be an IPA Package and set the Identity to your Developer Provisioning Profile with your Test User's device
5. Save the IPA somewhere and send to your Test User
6. Ask him to Sync the App onto his Device using iTunes or send it out via TestFlight App

For a more comprehensive and detailed guide, check out this post on creating an IPA: [How to create an IPA (Xcode 4)](http://support.testflightapp.com/kb/tutorials/how-to-create-an-ipa-xcode-4)

Comment: Thanks, will try when we are both free for testing.